# Vue2 Vite project with mixed TS and JS giving error TS9006

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, vite, pinia

I'm currently migrating an old Vue2 webpack (JS) project to Vite (mixed JS and TS).
I'm also migrating from Vuex to Pinia.

**store.ts**

```
interface UserLoginRequestI {
    emailOrUsername?: string;
    password?: string;
}

async login({ emailOrUsername, password }: UserLoginRequestI = {}) {
...
}
```

**Login.vue** (still JS)

```
import i18n from './dictionary';
import { useAuthStore } from '@/plugins/auth/store';
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'pinia';
...
methods: {
        ...mapActions(useAuthStore, ['login']),
    },
```

My issue is that I'm getting an error on the first import with the following content:

```
Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'UserLoginRequestI' from module '"./store/index"'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit.ts(9006)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I forgot to prepend interface forUserLoginRequestI with "**export**".

**store.ts**

```
export interface UserLoginRequestI {
    emailOrUsername?: string;
    password?: string;
}
```